# Newman projection of 3-methylpentane

Tags: organic-chemistry

How would you draw the Newman projections of [3-methylpentane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3-Methylpentane), sighting along the C3-C4 bond? I am unsure as to how to position the $\ce{-CH3}$ and $\ce{-CH2CH3}$ groups on the C3.
[image]

Comment: You can put them anywhere you want unless there is a specific conformation you are preferring.

Comment: I thought the biggest groups always had to point upwards? For example, I drew it with my front C3 attached to the ethyl (biggest grp) pointing straight up and the H and CH3 on the left and right. That way for my anti configuration, I had the methyl group on the back C4 180• to it. Am I correct in my reasoning?

Answer (score 6):

The Newman projections of 3-methylpentane are:

[image: staggered]

This is a staggered conformation.
Another one would be

[image: another staggered]

This is also a stggered conformation and is the most stable of conformers.

You can generate other conformers by rotating the C-3 or C-4 atom along the C-3 C-4 bond axis.[image: other conformers]

Comment: You should add that you only considered one enantiomer and that the mirror image of your drawings is equally a solution unless stereochemistry is specified.

Comment: @Jan , 3-methylpentane is achiral compound. How can you find enantiomer?

Comment: Yes, I later realised that how I wrote it didn’t make much sense but what I meant is: the two $\ce{C-C}$ bonds should be considered enantiotopic; looking down one will give you the opposite image from looking down the other. So in your pictures, you can exchange methyl and ethyl and still get a valid representation. That’s what I meant

Comment: @Jan , I kind of get what you mean but I am not sure how I can include them in my answer. As far as I see, exchanging the methyl and ethyl groups in one structure will result in a structure which can be obtained by rotating the original structure. However, feel free to edit my answer, in case I have missed your point.

Comment: Oh no, the key about these different versions is that they *cannot* be obtained by rotation, because switching the positions of only two substituents on one side of the Newman bond is equivalent to mirroring, not rotating. I can’t add any pictures right now (and at least until Monday) because I won’t have access to ChemDraw.

Comment: @Jan , consider the eclipsed structure at the bottom, and swap the positions of ethyl and methyl group. So, in the new structure, the overlapping groups are CH3-CH3, C2H5-H, H-H. This is exactly the same structure as the eclipsed structure on the upper right, and it has been generated by rotating the central bond. As you can see, they can be obtained by rotating the bond